# how to avoid flicker while using paint method to draw rectangle on panel?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserMouse, true);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);


        //this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        //this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        //this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);


        this.DoubleBuffered = true;

        Rect1LT.Width = 10;
        Rect1LT.Height = 10;
        Rect1L.Width = 10;
        Rect1L.Height = 10;
        Rect1RT.Width = 10;
        Rect1RT.Height = 10;
        Rect1B.Width = 10;
        Rect1B.Height = 10;
        Rect1RB.Width = 10;
        Rect1RB.Height = 10;
        Rect1R.Width = 10;
        Rect1R.Height = 10;
        Rect1LB.Width = 10;
        Rect1LB.Height = 10;
        Rect1T.Width = 10;
        Rect1T.Height = 10;

        Rect1.X = panel1.Location.X + 50;
        Rect1.Y = panel1.Location.Y + 50;
        Rect1.Width = 100;
        Rect1.Height = 100;

        Rect1LT.X = Rect1.X - 5;
        Rect1LT.Y = Rect1.Y - 5;

        Rect1RT.X = Rect1.X - 5 + Rect1.Width;
        Rect1RT.Y = Rect1.Y - 5;

        Rect1LB.X = Rect1.X - 5;
        Rect1LB.Y = Rect1.Y - 5 + Rect1.Height;

        Rect1RB.X = Rect1.X - 5 + Rect1.Width;
        Rect1RB.Y = Rect1.Y - 5 + Rect1.Height;

        Rect1T.X = Rect1.X - 5 + (Rect1.Width / 2);
        Rect1T.Y = Rect1.Y - 5;

        Rect1B.X = Rect1.X - 5 + (Rect1.Width / 2);
        Rect1B.Y = Rect1.Y - 5 + Rect1.Height;

        Rect1L.X = Rect1.X - 5;
        Rect1L.Y = Rect1.Y - 5 + (Rect1.Height / 2);

        Rect1R.X = Rect1.X - 5 + Rect1.Width;
        Rect1R.Y = Rect1.Y - 5 + (Rect1.Height / 2);



    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {


    Pen mypen = default(Pen);
    mypen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red, 3);
    mypen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash;
    //For Dash Line in Rectangle 
    Pen mypen1 = default(Pen);
    mypen1 = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Blue, 1);
    mypen1.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash;

    L1 = Rect1LT.X + 5;
    T1 = Rect1LT.Y + 5;
    W1 = Rect1RB.X - Rect1LT.X;
    H1 = Rect1RB.Y - Rect1LT.Y;
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(mypen, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(L1, T1, W1, H1));
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(mypen1, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(L1, T1, W1, H1));

    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(Rect1LT.X, Rect1LT.Y, 10, 10));
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(Rect1RT.X, Rect1RT.Y, 10, 10));
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(Rect1LB.X, Rect1LB.Y, 10, 10));
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(Rect1RB.X, Rect1RB.Y, 10, 10));

    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, Rect1LT);
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, Rect1RT);
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, Rect1LB);
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, Rect1RB);

    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(Rect1T.X, Rect1T.Y, 10, 10));
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(Rect1R.X, Rect1R.Y, 10, 10));
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(Rect1B.X, Rect1B.Y, 10, 10));
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(Rect1L.X, Rect1L.Y, 10, 10));

    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, Rect1T);
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, Rect1R);
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, Rect1B);
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, Rect1L);


}

int L1;
int T1;
int W1;
int H1;
bool flg1_LT = false;
bool flg1_RT = false;
bool flg1_LB = false;
bool flg1_RB = false;
bool flg1_mid = false;
bool flg1_T = false;
bool flg1_B = false;
bool flg1_L = false;

bool flg1_R = false;
public System.Drawing.Rectangle Rect1;
public System.Drawing.Rectangle Rect1LT;
public System.Drawing.Rectangle Rect1RT;
public System.Drawing.Rectangle Rect1LB;
public System.Drawing.Rectangle Rect1RB;
public System.Drawing.Rectangle Rect1T;
public System.Drawing.Rectangle Rect1B;
public System.Drawing.Rectangle Rect1L;

public System.Drawing.Rectangle Rect1R;
public Point Point1LT;
public Point Point1RT;
public Point Point1LB;
public Point Point1RB;
public Point Point1L;
public Point Point1T;
public Point Point1R;

public Point Point1B;

private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Location.X >= Rect1LT.X & e.Location.Y >= Rect1LT.Y & e.Location.X <= (Rect1LT.X + 10) & e.Location.Y <= (Rect1LT.Y + 10))
    {
        flg1_LT = true;
    }
    else if (e.Location.X >= Rect1RT.X & e.Location.Y >= Rect1RT.Y & e.Location.X <= (Rect1RT.X + 10) & e.Location.Y <= (Rect1RT.Y + 10))
    {
        flg1_RT = true;
    }
    else if (e.Location.X >= Rect1LB.X & e.Location.Y >= Rect1LB.Y & e.Location.X <= (Rect1LB.X + 10) & e.Location.Y <= (Rect1LB.Y + 10))
    {
        flg1_LB = true;
    }
    else if (e.Location.X >= Rect1RB.X & e.Location.Y >= Rect1RB.Y & e.Location.X <= (Rect1RB.X + 10) & e.Location.Y <= (Rect1RB.Y + 10))
    {
        flg1_RB = true;
    }
    else if (e.Location.X >= Rect1B.X & e.Location.Y >= Rect1B.Y & e.Location.X <= (Rect1B.X + 10) & e.Location.Y <= (Rect1B.Y + 10))
    {
        flg1_B = true;
    }
    else if (e.Location.X >= Rect1R.X & e.Location.Y >= Rect1R.Y & e.Location.X <= (Rect1R.X + 10) & e.Location.Y <= (Rect1R.Y + 10))
    {
        flg1_R = true;
    }
    else if (e.Location.X >= Rect1T.X & e.Location.Y >= Rect1T.Y & e.Location.X <= (Rect1T.X + 10) & e.Location.Y <= (Rect1T.Y + 10))
    {
        flg1_T = true;
    }
    else if (e.Location.X >= Rect1L.X & e.Location.Y >= Rect1L.Y & e.Location.X <= (Rect1L.X + 10) & e.Location.Y <= (Rect1L.Y + 10))
    {
        flg1_L = true;
    }
    else if (e.Location.X >= (Rect1LT.X + 10) & e.Location.Y >= (Rect1LT.Y + 10) & e.Location.X <= (Rect1RB.X + 10) & e.Location.Y <= (Rect1RB.Y + 10))
    {
        flg1_mid = true;

        temp1X = e.Location.X;
        temp1Y = e.Location.Y;

        Point1L.X = Rect1L.X;
        Point1T.X = Rect1T.X;
        Point1B.X = Rect1B.X;
        Point1R.X = Rect1R.X;
        Point1L.Y = Rect1L.Y;
        Point1T.Y = Rect1T.Y;
        Point1B.Y = Rect1B.Y;
        Point1R.Y = Rect1R.Y;
        Point1LT.X = Rect1LT.X;
        Point1LB.X = Rect1LB.X;
        Point1RT.X = Rect1RT.X;
        Point1RB.X = Rect1RB.X;
        Point1LT.Y = Rect1LT.Y;
        Point1LB.Y = Rect1LB.Y;
        Point1RT.Y = Rect1RT.Y;
        Point1RB.Y = Rect1RB.Y;

        this.panel1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.SizeAll;
}


}
int temp1X;
int temp1Y;
private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    System.Drawing.Rectangle Rect_TEMP1 = default(System.Drawing.Rectangle);
    System.Drawing.Rectangle Rect_TEMP2 = default(System.Drawing.Rectangle);
    System.Drawing.Rectangle Rect_TEMP3 = default(System.Drawing.Rectangle);
    System.Drawing.Rectangle Rect_TEMP4 = default(System.Drawing.Rectangle);
    System.Drawing.Rectangle Rect_TEMP5 = default(System.Drawing.Rectangle);
    System.Drawing.Rectangle Rect_TEMP6 = default(System.Drawing.Rectangle);

    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        Rect1T.X = ((Rect1LT.X + Rect1RB.X) / 2);
        Rect1L.Y = (Rect1LT.Y + Rect1LB.Y) / 2;
        Rect1R.Y = (Rect1LT.Y + Rect1LB.Y) / 2;
        Rect1B.X = ((Rect1LT.X + Rect1RB.X) / 2);


        if (flg1_LT)
        {
            if (e.Location.X > Rect1LT.X)
            {
                Rect1LT.X = e.Location.X;
                Rect1LB.X = e.Location.X;
                Rect1L.X = e.Location.X;
                Rect1T.X = ((Rect1LT.X + Rect1RB.X) / 2);
            }
            if (e.Location.Y > Rect1LT.Y)
            {
                Rect1LT.Y = e.Location.Y;
                Rect1RT.Y = e.Location.Y;
                Rect1T.Y = e.Location.Y;
                Rect1L.Y = (Rect1LT.Y + Rect1LB.Y) / 2;
            }
            if (e.Location.X < Rect1LT.X)
            {
                Rect1LT.X = e.Location.X;
                Rect1LB.X = e.Location.X;
                Rect1L.X = e.Location.X;
                Rect1T.X = ((Rect1LT.X + Rect1RB.X) / 2);
            }
            if (e.Location.Y < Rect1LT.Y)
            {
                Rect1LT.Y = e.Location.Y;
                Rect1RT.Y = e.Location.Y;
                Rect1T.Y = e.Location.Y;
                Rect1L.Y = (Rect1LT.Y + Rect1LB.Y) / 2;
            }



        }
        else if (flg1_RT)
        {
            if (e.Location.X > Rect1RT.X)
            {
                Rect1RT.X = e.Location.X;
                Rect1RB.X = e.Location.X;
                Rect1R.X = e.Location.X;
                Rect1T.X = ((Rect1LT.X + Rect1RB.X) / 2);
            }
            if (e.Location.Y > Rect1RT.Y)
            {
                Rect1RT.Y = e.Location.Y;
                Rect1LT.Y = e.Location.Y;
                Rect1T.Y = e.Location.Y;
                Rect1R.Y = (Rect1LT.Y + Rect1LB.Y) / 2;
            }
            if (e.Location.X < Rect1RT.X)
            {
                Rect1RT.X = e.Location.X;
                Rect1RB.X = e.Location.X;
                Rect1R.X = e.Location.X;
                Rect1T.X = ((Rect1LT.X + Rect1RB.X) / 2);
            }
            if (e.Location.Y < Rect1RT.Y)
            {
                Rect1RT.Y = e.Location.Y;
                Rect1LT.Y = e.Location.Y;
                Rect1T.Y = e.Location.Y;
                Rect1R.Y = (Rect1LT.Y + Rect1LB.Y) / 2;
            }


        }
        else if (flg1_LB)
        {
            if (e.Location.X > Rect1LB.X)
            {
                Rect1LB.X = e.Location.X;
                Rect1LT.X = e.Location.X;
                Rect1L.X = e.Location.X;
                Rect1B.X = ((Rect1LT.X + Rect1RB.X) / 2);
                Rect1T.X = ((Rect1LT.X + Rect1RB.X) / 2);
            }
            if (e.Location.Y > Rect1LB.Y)
            {
                Rect1LB.Y = e.Location.Y;
                Rect1RB.Y = e.Location.Y;
                Rect1B.Y = e.Location.Y;
                Rect1L.Y = (Rect1LT.Y + Rect1LB.Y) / 2;
            }
            if (e.Location.X < Rect1LB.X)
            {
                Rect1LB.X = e.Location.X;
                Rect1LT.X = e.Location.X;
                Rect1L.X = e.Location.X;
                Rect1B.X = ((Rect1LT.X + Rect1RB.X) / 2);
                Rect1T.X = ((Rect1LT.X + Rect1RB.X) / 2);
            }
            if (e.Location.Y < Rect1LB.Y)
            {
                Rect1LB.Y = e.Location.Y;
                Rect1RB.Y = e.Location.Y;
                Rect1B.Y = e.Location.Y;
                Rect1L.Y = (Rect1LT.Y + Rect1LB.Y) / 2;
            }


        }
        else if (flg1_RB)
        {
            if (e.Location.X > Rect1RB.X)
            {
                Rect1RB.X = e.Location.X;
                Rect1RT.X = e.Location.X;
                Rect1R.X = e.Location.X;
                Rect1B.X = ((Rect1LT.X + Rect1RB.X) / 2);
                Rect1T.X = ((Rect1LT.X + Rect1RB.X) / 2);
            }
            if (e.Location.Y > Rect1RB.Y)
            {
                Rect1RB.Y = e.Location.Y;
                Rect1LB.Y = e.Location.Y;
                Rect1B.Y = e.Location.Y;
                Rect1R.Y = (Rect1LT.Y + Rect1LB.Y) / 2;
            }
            if (e.Location.X < (Rect1RB.X + 10))
            {
                Rect1RB.X = e.Location.X;
                Rect1RT.X = e.Location.X;
                Rect1R.X = e.Location.X;
                Rect1B.X = ((Rect1LT.X + Rect1RB.X) / 2);
                Rect1T.X = ((Rect1LT.X + Rect1RB.X) / 2);
            }
            if (e.Location.Y < (Rect1RB.Y + 10))
            {
                Rect1RB.Y = e.Location.Y;
                Rect1LB.Y = e.Location.Y;
                Rect1B.Y = e.Location.Y;
                Rect1R.Y = (Rect1LT.Y + Rect1LB.Y) / 2;
            }


        }
        else if (flg1_B)
        {
            if (e.Location.Y > Rect1B.Y)
            {
                Rect1B.Y = e.Location.Y;
                Rect1LB.Y = e.Location.Y;
                Rect1RB.Y = e.Location.Y;
            }
            if (e.Location.Y < (Rect1B.Y + 10))
            {
                Rect1B.Y = e.Location.Y;
                Rect1LB.Y = e.Location.Y;
                Rect1RB.Y = e.Location.Y;
            }


        }
        else if (flg1_T)
        {
            if (e.Location.Y > Rect1T.Y)
            {
                Rect1T.Y = e.Location.Y;
                Rect1LT.Y = e.Location.Y;
                Rect1RT.Y = e.Location.Y;
            }

            if (e.Location.Y < (Rect1T.Y + 10))
            {
                Rect1T.Y = e.Location.Y;
                Rect1LT.Y = e.Location.Y;
                Rect1RT.Y = e.Location.Y;
            }


        }
        else if (flg1_R)
        {
            if (e.Location.X > Rect1R.X)
            {
                Rect1R.X = e.Location.X;
                Rect1RT.X = e.Location.X;
                Rect1RB.X = e.Location.X;
            }

            if (e.Location.X < (Rect1R.X + 10))
            {
                Rect1R.X = e.Location.X;
                Rect1RT.X = e.Location.X;
                Rect1RB.X = e.Location.X;
            }


        }
        else if (flg1_L)
        {
            if (e.Location.X > Rect1L.X)
            {
                Rect1L.X = e.Location.X;
                Rect1LT.X = e.Location.X;
                Rect1LB.X = e.Location.X;
            }

            if (e.Location.X < (Rect1L.X + 10))
            {
                Rect1L.X = e.Location.X;
                Rect1LT.X = e.Location.X;
                Rect1LB.X = e.Location.X;
            }


        }
        else if (flg1_mid)
        {
            Rect1LT.X = Point1LT.X + (e.Location.X - temp1X);
            Rect1RT.X = Point1RT.X + (e.Location.X - temp1X);
            Rect1LB.X = Point1LB.X + (e.Location.X - temp1X);
            Rect1RB.X = Point1RB.X + (e.Location.X - temp1X);
            Rect1LT.Y = Point1LT.Y + (e.Location.Y - temp1Y);
            Rect1RT.Y = Point1RT.Y + (e.Location.Y - temp1Y);
            Rect1LB.Y = Point1LB.Y + (e.Location.Y - temp1Y);
            Rect1RB.Y = Point1RB.Y + (e.Location.Y - temp1Y);
            Rect1L.X = Point1L.X + (e.Location.X - temp1X);
            Rect1R.X = Point1R.X + (e.Location.X - temp1X);
            Rect1B.X = Point1B.X + (e.Location.X - temp1X);
            Rect1T.X = Point1T.X + (e.Location.X - temp1X);
            Rect1L.Y = Point1L.Y + (e.Location.Y - temp1Y);
            Rect1R.Y = Point1R.Y + (e.Location.Y - temp1Y);
            Rect1B.Y = Point1B.Y + (e.Location.Y - temp1Y);
            Rect1T.Y = Point1T.Y + (e.Location.Y - temp1Y);

        }

        Rect1T.X = ((Rect1LT.X + Rect1RB.X) / 2);
        Rect1L.Y = (Rect1LT.Y + Rect1LB.Y) / 2;
        Rect1R.Y = (Rect1LT.Y + Rect1LB.Y) / 2;
        Rect1B.X = ((Rect1LT.X + Rect1RB.X) / 2);

        if (Rect1LT.X > Rect1RT.X)
        {
            Rect_TEMP1 = Rect1RT;
            Rect_TEMP2 = Rect1R;
            Rect_TEMP3 = Rect1RB;
            Rect1RT = Rect1LT;
            Rect1R = Rect1L;
            Rect1RB = Rect1LB;
            Rect1LT = Rect_TEMP1;
            Rect1L = Rect_TEMP2;
            Rect1LB = Rect_TEMP3;

        }
        if (Rect1LT.Y > Rect1LB.Y)
        {
            Rect_TEMP4 = Rect1LB;
            Rect_TEMP5 = Rect1B;
            Rect_TEMP6 = Rect1RB;
            Rect1LB = Rect1LT;
            Rect1B = Rect1T;
            Rect1RB = Rect1RT;
            Rect1LT = Rect_TEMP4;
            Rect1T = Rect_TEMP5;
            Rect1RT = Rect_TEMP6;
        }
        this.DoubleBuffered= true;
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint |
      ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
      ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw |
      ControlStyles.ContainerControl |
      ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
      ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor
      , true);

        panel1.Invalidate();
        //public void Invalidate(Rectangle);
        //panel1.Update();
        //panel1.Refresh();
        //panel1.Invalidate(Rect1T);
        //invalidateRect(Rect_TEMP1);
        //panel1.Invalidate(Rect_TEMP1);
        //panel1.Invalidate(Rect_TEMP2);
        //panel1.Invalidate(Rect_TEMP3);
        //panel1.Invalidate(Rect_TEMP4);
        //panel1.Invalidate(Rect_TEMP5);
        //panel1.Invalidate(Rect_TEMP6);
        //panel1.Invalidate(Rect1);
        //panel1.Invalidate(Rect1B);
        //Invalidate(Rect1L, true);
        //Invalidate(Rect_TEMP1,true);

        //panel1.Invalidate(Rect1LB);
        //panel1.Invalidate(Rect1LT);
        //panel1.Invalidate(Rect1R);
        //panel1.Invalidate(Rect1RB);
        //panel1.Invalidate(Rect1T);
        //panel1.Invalidate(Rect1RT);

        //panel1.Invalidate(Rect);
    }

    if (e.Location.X >= Rect1LT.X & e.Location.Y >= Rect1LT.Y & e.Location.X <= (Rect1LT.X + 10) & e.Location.Y <= (Rect1LT.Y + 10))
    {
        this.panel1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.SizeNWSE;
    }
    else if (e.Location.X >= Rect1RT.X & e.Location.Y >= Rect1RT.Y & e.Location.X <= (Rect1RT.X + 10) & e.Location.Y <= (Rect1RT.Y + 10))
    {
        this.panel1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.SizeNESW;
    }
    else if (e.Location.X >= Rect1LB.X & e.Location.Y >= Rect1LB.Y & e.Location.X <= (Rect1LB.X + 10) & e.Location.Y <= (Rect1LB.Y + 10))
    {
        this.panel1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.SizeNESW;
    }
    else if (e.Location.X >= Rect1RB.X & e.Location.Y >= Rect1RB.Y & e.Location.X <= (Rect1RB.X + 10) & e.Location.Y <= (Rect1RB.Y + 10))
    {
        this.panel1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.SizeNWSE;
    }
    else if (e.Location.X >= Rect1B.X & e.Location.Y >= Rect1B.Y & e.Location.X <= (Rect1B.X + 10) & e.Location.Y <= (Rect1B.Y + 10))
    {
        this.panel1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.SizeNS;
    }
    else if (e.Location.X >= Rect1R.X & e.Location.Y >= Rect1R.Y & e.Location.X <= (Rect1R.X + 10) & e.Location.Y <= (Rect1R.Y + 10))
    {
        this.panel1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.SizeWE;
    }
    else if (e.Location.X >= Rect1T.X & e.Location.Y >= Rect1T.Y & e.Location.X <= (Rect1T.X + 10) & e.Location.Y <= (Rect1T.Y + 10))
    {
        this.panel1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.SizeNS;
    }
    else if (e.Location.X >= Rect1L.X & e.Location.Y >= Rect1L.Y & e.Location.X <= (Rect1L.X + 10) & e.Location.Y <= (Rect1L.Y + 10))
    {
        this.panel1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.SizeWE;
    }
    else if (e.Location.X >= (Rect1LT.X + 10) & e.Location.Y >= (Rect1LT.Y + 10) & e.Location.X <= (Rect1RB.X + 10) & e.Location.Y <= (Rect1RB.Y + 10))
    {
        this.panel1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.SizeAll;
    }
}

    private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        flg1_LB = false;
        flg1_LT = false;
        flg1_RB = false;
        flg1_RT = false;
        temp1X = 0;
        temp1Y = 0;
        flg1_B = false;
        flg1_L = false;
        flg1_R = false;
        flg1_T = false;
        flg1_mid = false;
    }
}
```

As shown above I am drawing Rectangle , it causes flickering on panel?
I also set Double Buffered Property to true but still result is zero.
I set background Image in panel and Image Property is set as stretch, if Image Property is tile it doesn't flicker. 
what changes I should make to avoid flickering.

Comment: I haven't looked very closely at your scenario, but try calling `UpdateStyles();` after your SetStyle() calls in the Constructor.

Comment: I tried that but still it flickers.

Answer (score 0):

Setting DoubleBuffered property is not a magic that will prevent any flickering.
This property only allows a drawn surface to be rendered at once, instead of trying to directly render it progressively, you first draw all the graphic into a buffer. And then swap it to the effective surface to be drawn. This is done transparently for you but this is nothing more.

If you still have flickering, you may be incorrectly accessing the surface you are drawing to.
There is two main ways of driving graphical operations on your programs:

- Events message queue
- Game loop

The *events message queue* is primarily used when the graphics are to be updated upon an action triggered by the user or the system. A mouse click, a system notification, a keyboard key pressed, ...
This is events driven, and waiting for new events is a blocking operation. So there may be enough time between each of events processing for the cpu to perform other operations. This said you can perform some graphical operations without too much performance hits (and therefore flickering) if your events are coming at a rate lower than the time needed to draw to the surface.

```
while (!exit)
{
    var msg = WaitForMessage(); // Blocks until message arrives
    switch (msg.Type)
    {
        case Message.MouseMove: OnMouseMove(msg); break;
        case Message.Paint: OnPaint(msg); break;
        ...
    }
}
```

Source: [opentk](http://www.opentk.com/doc/intro/cpu-usage)

The *game loop* is a better approach when you need to continuously draw to a graphic surface and/or the graphics are to be updated without user interaction.

```
while (!exit)
{
    var time = GetTime();
    Update(time);
    Render(time);
}
```

Source: [opentk](http://www.opentk.com/doc/intro/cpu-usage)

With this approach you perform non-blocking operations and therefore have to handle free cpu time for other applications or you will be consuming 100% of the cpu time.
This is the basic of the FPS control.

Your code is using the first approach because after each mouse move event you invalidate your drawn surface and request a graphic update.

This is not a good approach as mouse move events may come quicker compared to the time you will take to perform the drawing. This may slow down the responsiveness of your UI.

You may consider working on the following points:

- Reduce the time taken by your graphic updates:

  - Avoid systematic instantiating of new objects on the heap in your paint operation.  Try reusing fixed instances. Set the styles and color used one time. There is no need to repeat it over and over.
- Break the link between the mouse move and the graphics invalidation:

  - Try creating a game loop, where your invalidate calls will be performed at a well know rate independently of the mouse move events. This will give you a control over the FPS.
- Invalidate only what needs to be invalidated:

  - You may gain performance by redrawing only what needs to be.
    Invalidate method as an overload accepting a rectangle describing the region that will be redrawn on the paint method. This will avoid always redrawing pixels that do not change.

All these actions will increase performance and reduce flickering effects.